# Does this simple non-convex problem involving discrete phase shifts have an exact solution?

Tags: co.combinatorics, nonlinear-optimization, combinatorial-optimization, integer-programming

Let the optimization problem be
\begin{equation}
 \max_{\phi_n} \left|\sum_{n=1}^N e^{i\phi_n} a_n \right|,
\end{equation}
where $a_n\in\mathbb{C}$ and the optimization variables have discrete phase shifts $\phi_n\in\{0,\frac{1}{M}2\pi\ldots,\frac{M-1}{M}2\pi\}$ for some positive integer $M$.

Can this problem's exact solution be computed efficiently?

**Edit:** By efficient I mean that complexity does not grow exponentially with $N$.

Comment: Do you need that all $\phi_n$ are distinct or could you take $\phi_n=0$ for all $n$?

Comment: in principal you could test all possibilities (there are only finitely many). More efficiently one can us that the phase of the summands of the functional deviate at most $2\pi/M$. There are at least M optimal solution as adding the same constant to a solution does not change the value of the functional.

Comment: @Dirk They can be the same.

Comment: @Markus Thanks. I actually think I figured out the solution using your same reasoning. I will post it here later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So indeed it exists an efficient algorithm for computing the solution to this non-convex problem.

Let $\delta=2\pi/M$ and let $\angle$ denote the phase of a complex number (in radians). Upon defining $r_n=e^{i\phi_n}a_n$, the optimization problem can be recast as
\begin{equation}
 \max_{r_n} \left|\sum_{n=1}^N r_n\right|,
\end{equation}
subject to $|r_n|=|a_n|$ and $\angle r_n=\angle a_n+\delta \, k_n$ for some integer $k_n$ and for all $n$. If this problem is solved, then the solution to the original problem is $\phi_n=\delta \, k_n$ for all $n$.

It is not too hard to prove (left as an exercise to the reader) that any globoal maximizer satisfies
\begin{equation}
 \left|\angle r_n- \angle r_p\right|_{\text{wa}}\leq\delta
\end{equation}
for any $n,p$. Here, $|\angle r_n- \angle r_p|_{\text{wa}}$ is the wrap-around phase difference, so as an example, for $\angle r_n =\frac{3\pi}{2}$ and $\angle r_p =0$, the phase difference is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and not $\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

The above conclusion can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
 \psi\leq \angle r_n \leq\psi+\delta,
\end{equation}
for an unknown $\psi$ and for all $n$ such that $a_n \neq 0$. Furthermore, it exists only one feasible value of $r_n$ satisfying the above condition (except if $\angle a_n = \psi$, in which case $\angle a_n = \psi+\delta$ is also feasible). Therefore, the problem boils down to a 1-dimensional search over $\psi$.

With this in mind, the global maximizer can be found with the following algorithm:

1. let $\Omega_n$ be a permutation such that $0\leq \operatorname{mod}(\angle a_{\Omega_1},\delta)\leq\cdots\leq\operatorname{mod}(\angle a_{\Omega_N},\delta)$
2. set $v_n$ such that $|v_n|=|a_{\Omega_n}|$ and $\angle v_n=\operatorname{mod}(\angle a_{\Omega_n},\delta)$ for $n=1,\ldots,N$
3. initialize $S=0$
4. **for** $p=1,\ldots,N$ **do**
5. $\hspace{3ex}$ **if** $|\sum_{n=1}^N v_n|>S$ **then**
6. $\hspace{6ex} S=|\sum_{n=1}^N v_n|$
7. $\hspace{6ex} \phi_{\Omega_n} = \angle v_n-\angle a_{\Omega_n}$
8. $\hspace{3ex}$ **end if**
9. $\hspace{3ex} \angle v_p \leftarrow  \angle v_p + \delta$
10. **end for**